# Group an array of objects by one of its elements

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have an array of objects that looks like this

```
arr = [{
  group: "Forest",
  value: "81.8",
  year: 2015
}, {
  group: "Forest",
  value: "86.4",
  year: 2016
}, {
  group: "Forest",
  value: "67.3",
  year: 2017
}, {
  group: "Forest",
  value: "70.8",
  year: 2018
}, {
  group: "Forest",
  value: "67.6",
  year: 2019
}, {
  group: "Mountain",
  value: "78.6",
  year: 2015
}, {
  group: "Mountain",
  value: "83.1",
  year: 2016
}, {
  group: "Mountain",
  value: "65.6",
  year: 2017
}, {
  group: "Mountain",
  value: "68.1",
  year: 2018
}, {
  group: "Mountain",
  value: "63.7",
  year: 2019
}];
```

Is there a way to group this array by group? I want to create something like this or alike:

```
arr = [{
    group: "Forest",
    val2015: 81.8,
    val2016: 86.4,
    val2017: 67.3,
    val2018: 70.8,
    val2019: 67.6
},{
    group: "Mountain",
    val2015: 78.6,
    val2016: 83.1,
    val2017: 65.6,
    val2018: 68.1,
    val2019: 63.7
}];
```

Is it possible to do that with js, or maybe I can send arr to ajax and do this with php then return it?

Comment: There are many Q&A about grouping arrays by properties... what did you research?

Comment: I searched this https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-group-by-array-of-objects-using-a-key/ they use Array.reduce then create groupBy function

Comment: I'd say, have a go at it? Was there a problem?

Comment: everything I searched so far was helpful but didn't quite solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Map` to key the groups by the group strings, and associate to those keys plain objects, each with the group property.

Then iterate the data to populate those objects by year/value combinations.

Finally extract those objects from the Map:

```js
const arr = [{group: "Forest",value: "81.8",year: 2015}, {group: "Forest",value: "86.4",year: 2016}, {group: "Forest",value: "67.3",year: 2017}, {group: "Forest",value: "70.8",year: 2018}, {group: "Forest",value: "67.6",year: 2019}, {group: "Mountain",value: "78.6",year: 2015}, {group: "Mountain",value: "83.1",year: 2016}, {group: "Mountain",value: "65.6",year: 2017}, {group: "Mountain",value: "68.1",year: 2018}, {group: "Mountain",value: "63.7",year: 2019}];

const groups = new Map(arr.map(({group}) => [group, { group }]));
for (const {group, value, year} of arr) {
    groups.get(group)["val" + year] = +value;
}
const result = [...groups.values()];

console.log(result);
```